# Вызов второго activity через некоторое время

Tags: java, android, activity, sleep, android-handler

Необходимо

```
    1. Открыть первое активити.
    2. Подождать 3 секунды.
    3. Открыть второе активити.
```

Какой из вариантов лучше? Через `Runnable` или через `sleep`?

Первый вариант

```
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
    };
    Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(r, 3000);
```

Второй вариант

```
    try {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Вы делаете сплэш-скрин?

Comment: Определенно через Runnable. Потому что sleep блокирует основной поток приложения. Пользователь нажмёт назад, приложение не ответит и система предложит его убить, а это не есть хорошо

Comment: @pavlofff, ага сплэш скрин.

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко, а я тут подумал - разве можно вызывать второй активити из runnable указывая параметр this?

Comment: @androman можно написать ActivityOne.this, где ActivityOne - имя класса текущей активити. Или можно явно вызвать функцию  getApplicationContext

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко, вот так Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOne.class, ActivityTwo.class);?

Comment: Посмотрите ещё раз на мой комментарий, повнимательнее:)

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко, еще один вопросик. Что будет если во время ожидания в три секунды юзер нажмет на кнопочку назад. Это верхний первый активити. И поэтому апп должен закрытся. А что будет с Runnable. Он через три секунды запустит апп снова?

Comment: Активити все равно запустится. По крайней мере на 7.1.1 Андроиде. Хотя потенциально, здесь может быть вылет, ведь при выходе контекст уничтожается. Вообще есть неплохая статья про Splash на хабре. Почитайте: https://habrahabr.ru/post/312516/

Comment: Для реализации splash-creen не нужно ставить таймер отображения, это повлечет не очевидные проблемы. Смотрите правильную реализацию (через фон темы) в статье на хабре из комента выше.

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко Оформите ответом

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко, в варианте на хабре апп же не ждет три секунды, а сразу загрузит второй активити после первого. Хотя зачем мне делать трехсекундную паузу?

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко Наверное Вы и правы. Не надо мучить юзера моим трехсекундным самолюбием. Буду использовать Ваш вариант.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Андроид придерживается политики, что не следует мучить пользователя лишним ожиданием. Но все же нужно, что-то показывать пока происходит подгрузка данных инициализация и прочее. Splash экран отличается от любых других тем, что он должен показываться моментально. Поэтому обычная Activity с "лёгким" layout'ом в качестве splash не очень подходит. Но есть способ сделать это:
Первым делом нужно создать изображение которое представляет собой Splash Screen. Примерный шаблон:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@color/gray"/>
  <item>
    <bitmap android:gravity="center"
      android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

После этого нужно создать тему, у которой в качестве фона установить созданный ранее Drawable:

```
<style name="SplashTheme"
parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
  <item
    name="android:windowBackground">
      @drawable/background_splash
  </item>
</style>
```

Теперь осталось дело за малым. Нужно создать активити, в манифесте прописать для нее Splash тему, а также интент-фильтр для того, чтобы первым запускалась именно эта активность.

Ну и далее в onCreate этой активити вызываем переход к нужной активити:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  finish();
}
```

Обратите внимание, что нет вызова setContentView, потому что активность сразу осуществляет переход.

Источник: [ссылка](https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/312516/)

Answer (score 4):

> Какой из вариантов лучше? Через `Runnable` или через `sleep`?

Из этих двух – с помощью `Runnable`. И на будущее – **забудьте про `sleep(...)` на UI-потоке**, ибо тем самым Вы повесите интерфейс, и, если задержка будет более 5 секунд, то Вы получите [ANR](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html#anr).

А вообще, имхо, не следует делать искусственную *задержку*. Показывайте splash screen **ровно столько времени**, сколько требуется на запуск Вашего приложения. Вот  [здесь](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) есть пример:

**@drawable/background_splash**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/gray"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**@style/SplashTheme**:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**SplashActivity**:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Еще советую ознакомиться вот с [этой](http://saulmm.github.io/avoding-android-cold-starts) статьей.